# Select Object by Id in Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

In Titanium how do you select an object by the id?

Working with Titanium I created a view with children.  I set an event listener on the parent view so I didn't have to create an event listener for each child.  In the event listener I determine which child view was clicked by using `e.source.id`.  I need to change the height of the view as it's clicked, and I also need to change the height of previous view that was open.  (This is all to show the active view with an underline type of style.)

```
    var selectionView = Ti.UI.createView({
    title: 'Selection View',
    width: Ti.UI.Fill,
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
    layout: 'horizontal',
    height: 32,
    zIndex: 12
    });

    var selection_Type = Ti.UI.createView({
    title: "Type View",
    width: Ti.UI.Fill,
    layout: 'horizontal',
    backgroundColor: '#ABABAB',
    top: 0,
    height: 30
    });
```

I can't figure out how to select the object by the id name so I can change it's height.

```
//storing the id of the last clicked feed label so we can change it's height when it's no longer open
var feedSelector = 'selection_All';

selection_Type.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
Ti.API.info( ' ==== Select Destination Hit ==== '  + e.source.id);
if (e.source.id === feedSelector)   {
            //refresh the feed view
            Ti.API.info('Simulating feed refresh for...' + e.source.id);
        }
        else {
            //reducing active label height to simulatue 2px underline
            e.source.setHeight(28);

            //reset previous selected label height
            //here's the problem
            //i know how to do this in regular javascript/html
            //but I don't know how to access an object by it's id in Titanium

           //setting current label id in feedSelector so we can change it's height next time a button is clicked
           feedSelector = e.source.id;
           Ti.API.info('Changed value for feedSelector to...' + feedSelector);
}
        }
        }

        );

        var selection_All = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        id: 'selection_All',
        text: 'All',
        width: '14.9%',
        top: 0,
        center: 2,
        height: 28,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        textAlign: Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
        color:'#073266',
        font:{fontFamily:'Trebuchet MS',fontSize:13}

        });

    var selection_Status = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        id: 'selection_Status',
        text: 'Status',
        width: '22%',
        top: 0,
        center: 0,
        height: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        textAlign: Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
        color:'#073266',
        font:{fontFamily:'Trebuchet MS',fontSize:13}
    });

    var selection_Article = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        id: 'selection_Article',
        text: 'Article',
        width: '23%',
        top: 0,
        center: 0,
        height: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        textAlign: Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
        color:'#073266',
        font:{fontFamily:'Trebuchet MS',fontSize:13}
    });

    var selection_Video = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        id: 'selection_Video',
        text: 'Video',
        width: '20%',
        top: 0,
        center: 0,
        height: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        textAlign: Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
        color:'#073266',
        font:{fontFamily:'Trebuchet MS',fontSize:13}
    });

    var selection_Audio = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        id: 'selection_Audio',
        text: 'Audio',
        width: '20%',
        top: 0,
        center: 0,
        height: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        textAlign: Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
        color:'#073266',
        font:{fontFamily:'Trebuchet MS',fontSize:13}
    });

    //creating selection type container and adding selection types
    selection_Type.add(selection_All);
    selection_Type.add(selection_Status);
    selection_Type.add(selection_Article);
    selection_Type.add(selection_Video);
    selection_Type.add(selection_Audio);
    selectionView.add(selection_Type);
```

Edit:  I accomplished what I needed to do using a switch statement, but it would be much cleaner if I could get the object by it's id.

```
var feedSelector = 'selection_All';

selection_Type.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
Ti.API.info( ' ==== Select Destination Hit ==== '  + e.source.id);
if (e.source.id === feedSelector)   {
    //refresh the feed view if the feed is open and button is clicked
    //Ti.API.info('Simulating feed refresh for...' + e.source.id);
    alert('Refreshing feed');
}
else {
    //reducing active label height to simulatue 2px underline
    e.source.setHeight(28);
    switch (feedSelector)   {
        case 'selection_All':
            selection_All.setHeight(30);
            break;
        case 'selection_Status':
            selection_Status.setHeight(30);
            break;
        case 'selection_Article':
            selection_Article.setHeight(30);
            break;
        case 'selection_Video':
            selection_Video.setHeight(30);
            break;
        case 'selection_Audio':
            selection_Audio.setHeight(30);
            break;
    }

    feedSelector = e.source.id;
    Ti.API.info('Changed value for feedSelector to...' + feedSelector);
}
}
```

);

Comment: If you're using Titanium Studio, just debug on the click event and examine the event object. On the breakpoints stop go to the **Expressions** tab enter the `e` event object and examine it. Probably the UI elemnt is there as a property.

Comment: I accomplished what I needed to using a switch statement.  This worked because there were only five objects in the view that I needed to change, but I still don't know how to get an object by it's id.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **Titanium Studio**, just debug on the click event and examine the event object. On the breakpoints stop go to the **Expressions** tab enter the `e` event object and examine it. Probably the UI elemnt is there as a property.

Other way around is:

```
var labelStore = {};


function createLabel(props){
   var label = Ti.UI.createLabel(props);
   labelStore[props.id] = label;

   return label;
}

function getLabelById(id){
   return labelStore[id];
}


var selection_Status = createLabel({
    id: 'selection_Status',
    ...
});
```

and then on **click**

```
var id = e.source.id;
var label = getLabelById(id);
```

....Do what you got to do with the label

Comment: Is there not an equivalent to `getObjectbyId(feedSelector)` like in regular javascript?

Comment: You meen like in DOM browser API not javascript generally. Only if you're using **Alloy** framework and working with XML doc. I haven't met such parctise in a such scenario yet but you can check the Titanium documentation.